# Kinect v1 Camera not connect with Kinect SDK

Tags: camera, kinect, depth, kinect-sdk

I tried to connect Kinect V1 depth camera with my windows lap. It couldn't connect with Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8. But i can use kinect with "Processing" IDE. I need to record 3D point cloud with kinect SDK. The Error message show like below screenshot. I downloaded "3D Scan" from windows store. But kinect not connected with SDK.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy7q7.jpg)

It couldn't connect with Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8. But i can use kinect with "Processing" IDE. I need to record 3D point cloud with kinect SDK. The Error message show like below screenshot. I downloaded "3D Scan" from windows store.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNxrE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

open kinect studio v1.8 and open kinect development toolkit. Run one of example in the development tool kit. Then click "refresh" in the studio v1.8. We can see kinect camera connect with kinect studio v1.8.